# CSS Cursor code - apparently wrong syntax

Tags: css, cursor

I tried to insert the following line of code in an external CSS stylesheet, but my Error Console told me there was an error parsing value for property 'cursor':

```
cursor: url(JC_puzzle_piece.cur) !important;
```

Is this not the proper syntax? If so, then what is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a fallback preset value in case the cursor file isn't found. See a list of presets [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cursor).

```
cursor: url(JC_puzzle_piece.cur), default !important;
```

Comment: Wait...I see you edited your post. You changed it from auto to default. Looking at the link you provided, I noticed it says for auto: "the browser’s default cursor in the current context". What exactly is this "current context" that it mentions? I'm asking because I already contacted my hosting provider before seeing your edit, and told them to change the CSS file to use the first version of the code you posted, which used auto instead of default, so I want that it will stick work. Otherwise, I'll need to contact them again. Thanks.

Comment: @CSS_coder_in_training: auto changes depending on whether your cursor is on a link, on text, or on another part of your page. I believe default is just the default arrow symbol. Why don't you have access to the files on your server?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I'll stick with auto then, as my website used a different cursor depending on the context before I attempted to make the change on the cursor. I don't have access to the files on my server because technically its not my website. I'm the son of the person who owns the website, who is basically turning the technical aspect of it over to me little by little, and I don't have access to the hosting account (yet), and so cannot change certain files of the website myself, that is why I'm getting my hosting company's support team to do it for me instead. :)